# MouseOut event not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, marionette

On of my designer given the following design.Actually it's a `td` element.What are the elements are there inside `td` all are in `div's`.

[image]

html structure:

```
<td class="banner">
 <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
 </div>
</td>
```

I written a `mouseout` event on `td` element,It's working fine but the problem is Even If I move a cursor on any element of the `td`,Event(`mouseOut`) is triggering that corresponding function.

What I want,once The cursor is out of `td`,then only It should be trigger the corresponding function.

What I tried:(I am using `marionette and backbone` in my Application)

```
events:{
 "mouseout .consumerCaption":"clearingBannerId",
},
clearingBannerId:function(){
  console.log("hi");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `mouseout` *bubbles*. So you receive `mouseout` events for the descendant elements of the `td`.

Two options:

1. A lot of people using Backbone also use jQuery. If you are, there is a related event pioneered by Microsoft, `mouseleave`, which doesn't bubble — and jQuery polyfills it for you on browsers that don't have it. So if you're using jQuery (or have any other scripts that polyfill it for you), you can use `mouseleave` rather than `mouseout` and you're done.
2. If you can't use `mouseleave`, then in your handler function, accept the event argument, and then check the type of the element the event originated in (`e.target.tagType`):

   ```
   clearingBannerId:function(e){
     if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "TD") {
         console.log("hi");
     }
   }
   ```

   That way, you're ignoring events that have bubbled from the descendant elements, only looking at the ones that come from the `td` itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to have any mouse interaction in the child elements of your `td`, you can use a css property called `pointer-events`.

The documentation tells us:

> **pointer-events: none**
>   The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

In your case you can try the following css rule:

```
td > div {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This way the only events triggered in that area will come from your `td` element.